I have a ginger root that sprouted suddenly. What do I do with it?

Here is a ginger root that I have in my kitchen. I see that it has some sprouts, as seen on a picture. I would like to grow more ginger, however I'm not yet sure whether it's okay to plant it now that it has these sprouts.
Any guidance on what to do is appreciated.

Welcome Rusurano. Horticulture is more suited to our [gardening.se] site (afaik). I've grown them indoors on a sunny windowsill for decorative purposes, but if you want to know about conditions for cropping, best to check-out the other site.

@JiminyCricket. Thanks for the warm welcome and for the tip! It doesn't feel like too offtopic for Biology either, so let's see what other people have to say for that here, too :)

What I did: In a wide pot with sandy loam (well drained), I placed it shoots facing upward, then buried the body about 2 cm (an inch), leaving the tips poking through, then watered lightly. It took a few weeks for the shoots to get going. I watered infrequently. A bit like a grass, the leaves unwrap themselves from the stem as it grows. Multiple shoots followed from the root. End of season, I uncovered the root - if anything it was smaller than when I planted it, the stems too fibrous to eat. You need advice from someone who's had more success with it than I : )
